# Get encrypted hash string of Cookie set by Slim Framework

Tags: php, cookies, encryption, hash, slim

How to get the encrypted hashed string in Slim Framework. I used:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'cookies.encrypt' => true,
    'cookies.secret_key' => 'MY_SECRET_KEY',
    'cookies.cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
    'cookies.cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
        ));

 $app->setCookie('_hsio', "My Data", '1 day');
 $app->getCookie('_hsio');
```

The above `$app->getCookie('_hsio');` will return the decrypted data but i want to get the encrypted hashed string set by `setCookie`. Any idea how to get that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that off of the Request object:

`$app->request->cookies->get('_hsio');`